TypeScript narrowing down a class not working
Here's a minimal snippet to reproduce this

class Stuff<InGuild extends boolean = boolean> {
    public inGuild(): this is Stuff<true> {
        return true;
    }
}

const x = new Stuff();

if (x.inGuild()) {

    
    x
}

Hover over x on VSCode and I see this:

x is still a Stuff<boolean> and not a Stuff<true>, why is that?
I got this idea from discord.js here and I wonder why they can do that and I'm not able to reproduce this here.

I think that's because your class is simple enough that there's no meaningful difference between Stuff<boolean> and Stuff<true>. Try adding more code to it

@NicholasTower ah thanks, that's quite interesting, I'm using it in an unusual way and so did discord.js but looking deeper into their code I realized they added this line to make it work https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/35207b0b31929558eee69f4bd53a6f9adadb0362/packages/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts#L2076 and on this line they left a comment for the reason https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/35207b0b31929558eee69f4bd53a6f9adadb0362/packages/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts#L1870 I don't really understand the reason but I guess I'll just follow that to get my code working

For some reason it is required to make use of that InGuild generic in some way or type guarding does not work.
So for the above code if we do this:
class Stuff<InGuild extends boolean = boolean> {
    // @ts-ignore
    private readonly _cacheType: InGuild;

    public inGuild(): this is Stuff<true> {
        return true;
    }
}

const x = new Stuff();

if (x.inGuild()) {

    
    x // <-- Now x is correctly a Stuff<true>
}

The aforementioned discord.js library also did this, example 1, example 2, example 3
Maybe our usecases for the feature is too niche/unusual I guess, but that works for now.
Edit: This did turn out to be a duplicate of this question so for future readers check that for detailed explanation, I just didn't know the right words to come across that question.
